# Reading XML via php

Tags: php, xml

so I have this XML which I'm trying to read via SimpleXML class of php.

```
<ns0:ASN xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ASN">
<CustPackingSlipJour xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ASN" class="entity">
<BON_FileNameSeqNum>4</BON_FileNameSeqNum>
<!-- funktionell: Internt löpnr  -->
<BON_TotalNetAmount>726.00</BON_TotalNetAmount>
<!-- funktionell: Totalt belopp  -->
<BON_TotalTaxAmount>181.50</BON_TotalTaxAmount>
<!-- funktionell: Momsbelopp  -->
<InvoiceAccount>9001</InvoiceAccount>
<!-- funktionell:  -->
<LanguageId>SV</LanguageId>
<!-- funktionell: Språk  -->
<OrderAccount>9001</OrderAccount>
<!-- funktionell: Butiks nr för intern användning! -->
<Qty>4.00</Qty>
<!-- funktionell: Total lev kvant!  -->
<SalesId>24</SalesId>
<!-- funktionell:Försäljningsordernr!  -->
<CustPackingSlipTrans class="entity">
<BON_LineNetAmount>149.00</BON_LineNetAmount>
<!-- funktionell: Orderradsbelopp! -->
<BON_SalesPrice>0.00</BON_SalesPrice>
<!-- funktionell: Försäljningspris!  -->
<DeliveryDate>2014-09-09</DeliveryDate>
<!-- funktionell: Leveransdag! -->
<ItemId>10001</ItemId>
<!-- funktionell: Artikelnr!  -->
<Ordered>1.00</Ordered>
<!-- funktionell:Beställd kvantitet!  -->
<PackingSlipId>00000004_061</PackingSlipId>
<!-- funktionell:  -->
<Qty>1.00</Qty>
<!-- funktionell:Levererad kvantitet!  -->
<InventReportDimHistory class="entity">
<InventDim class="entity"/>
</InventReportDimHistory>
</CustPackingSlipTrans>
```

I'm trying to access it's element by the code :-

```
<?php
$asn=simplexml_load_file("ASN.xml");
echo $asn->CustPackingSlipTrans[0]->ItemId;
?>
```

But this doesn't seems to be working. I get a blank output. I've read some tutorials bout the Simplexml class and reached to this code. But I'm not sure what wrong I'm doing here.
How would I access each and every element of the XML ?

All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML was properly indented, you'd see it's:

```
<CustPackingSlipJour ...>
    ...
    <CustPackingSlipTrans ...>
        ...
        <ItemId>10001</ItemId>
```

So your code should be:

```
echo $asn->CustPackingSlipJour[0]->CustPackingSlipTrans[0]->ItemId;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always try and follow this sequence :-

```
echo $objectname->parentname->childname->subchild
```

This always work. But, you should always have the XML indented. That's the primary requirement. If you have it indented, you can easily see which is the parent element and which is the child.